# Отображение изображения в recyclerView + Picasso

Tags: android, recyclerview, picasso

Без заглушки `.placeholder(R.drawable.nedostupno)` отображается список, содержащий ID и название изображения, а также другая информация в текстовом виде. Но из-за ошибки 504 не отображаются изображения.

Было решено добавить заглушку на случай ошибки. Но после добавления заглушки и `error()` теперь отображается только заглушка, а другие данные и текст пропадают.

Как сделать так, чтобы отображалась и заглушка и данные из других текст представлений?

```
Picasso.get().setLoggingEnabled(true)
    Picasso.get().load(full_img_url)
        .fit()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.nedostupno)
        .error(R.drawable.nedostupno)
        .into(holder.tvPoster)
```

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poster"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tvTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvimdb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/tvimdbID" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/tvType" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="@string/tvYear" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Если что-то пропадает - дело в разметке. Покажите её.

Comment: дополнен вопрос, добавлена разметка

Comment: А что у Вас тут tvPoster?

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" во втором LinearLayout нужно заменить на android:layout_width="wrap_content". Это как минимум.

Comment: tvPoster так названа переменная, которая во вьюхолдере в себе содержит  ImageView @+id/poster

Comment: Поставьте ширину картинке такую же как высота. Тогда она не будет пытаться занять всё нужное ей пространство.

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало!

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какой именно совет Вам помог и укажите это в комментариях, либо создайте правильный ответ на вопрос самостоятельно)

Comment: помогли оба ответа, стоило поправить и LinearLayout второй и ширину у картинки как высота. и сразу все заработало. Благодарю Вас!

Comment: @and пометьте ответ правильным ,если он Вам помог, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для корректной работы необходимо выполнить два действия:

1. Исправить ширину вложенного LinearLayout, заменив

   ```
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   ```

   на

   ```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   ```

   В противном случае, вложенный LinearLayout полностью занимает своего родителя, игнорируя другие элементы. (аналогично с `android:layout_height` для вертикальных LinearLayout).
2. Жестко задать ширину картинке, чтобы она не пыталась занять произвольный объем, то есть заменить

   ```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   ```

   на

   ```
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   ```

   Картинка теперь станет одинаковой по высоте и ширине.

   Авторство второй части ответа принадлежит @ЮрийСПб♦